# Detecting Memory leaks tools on Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, windows-phone

Does anyone know of any good tools to detect memory leaks on the Windows phone 7.5 platform?

Comment: Can you describe what happen? What language do you use? for C# most common memory leaks are caused by unsubscribed events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in profiling tools are probably the best starting point.

Select: Debug > Start Windows Phone Perfomance Analysis
and select the the "Memory" option

This will help you see any memory spikes and leaks and help you drill down to the cause.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934(v=vs.92).aspx
and
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/02/01/memory-profiling-for-application-performance.aspx
for more guidance on using the tool

Answer (score 1):

I have started a series of blog posts regarding the usage of this tool :-

http://smartmobidevice.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/windows-phone-performance-analysis-tool.html

You may also find the following blog post useful :-

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/05/10/memory-profiling-the-heap-summary-view.aspx