# Memory Issue in WP8 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

My app is like a tweet feed reader. But with use, the app's responsiveness slows down in the wp8 emulator. By being unresponsive, I mean the progress bar indicator speed slows down, no links respond, none of the app buttons respond and the app suddenly closes.

I think it is a memory issue with the emulator. Am I right? I can't test it as I don't have a device yet.

Even on increasing the memory using the Hyper-V settings I didn't observe much difference.

I have an in-app browser which works fine for the first 2-3 links but then makes the app hang!

Comment: Im not familar with WP8, does VS memory leak detection tool work for WP emulator?

Comment: using c# and XAML. I dont how to enable that feature on this platform.

Comment: There is memory leak detection for WP7. It is good chance WP8 has it too.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503069/detecting-memory-leaks-tools-on-wp7

Comment: I tried that too. The memory doesnt even cross 50Mb mark but eventually the inapp browser causes the app to hang. Works fine on WP7 Device though! WP8 is a concern :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a memory leak. What you're describing is a slow-down which is caused by putting too much work on the UI thread. Overall you should offload as much work as possible to a background thread or the compositor thread.

The app suddenly closes sounds like some unhandled exception, but it's hard to tell which one.  You said the app works fine on WP7. Have you looked at known app compatability issues that occur once WP7 apps are upgraded to WP8? Check it out on MSDN @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx

This really isn't enough to go on. Is there something printed out in the output window once the app crashes? Can you tell what's the last managed method to be invoked before the app crashes? Can you try profiling the app for CPU and see what's the method that's most invoked? And profile for memory  usage and see how's memory consumption right before the crash?